# logout code runs if the browser suggest the url

Tags: javascript, php

```
    /** LOGOUT PROCESS **/
case logout:
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['remember'])){
            list($selector, $authenticator) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['remember']);
            $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM user_token WHERE selector = :selector');
            $stmt->execute(['selector' => $selector]);
        }
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])){
            $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
            foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
                $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
                $name = trim($parts[0]);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
            }
        }
    }
    header("Location: ".site_url,true,303);
    exit();
    break;
```

I have the above code where the user visits: `example.com/user/logout` to run this process. As I was testing, I have noticed that if I type `example.com/user/lo` my browser suggests me to go to `example.com/user/logout` because that is the last page that I visited. What it does it logs me out without me visiting the url (the browser I guess visits the url if it was suggested to me). I do not want that to happen! I thought of designing a popup alert before requesting to logout to prevent it. but what are other options that I can use so the user does not get logged out instantly if the page was visited? I have seen websites that do not display alerts before someone tries to logout. What are they doing in the backend?

Comment: Logout only on `post` requests.

Comment: @Federkun that does not sound right. that means I have to have a form for my logout button `<form action="'.site_url.'/user/logout"><input type="submit" value="logout"></form>`

Comment: You don't want users to be able log out other users by simply adding `<img src="//example.com/user/logout">` somewhere. At least, add a `csrf/token` on the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post method or ajax request for the same. Currently you are using simple get method and you check that if user is logged in you simply logout user. 
 
1-> You can use post request for logout functionality with any particular key.
 
2-> You can use same with implementing ajax on page. 

 
You can use any method according to your choice.